# No Intellisense in views updating from ASP.NET MVC 4 to MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, intellisense

I just updated an mvc4 project (using vs2012) to mvc5. After having a lot of issues related to dependencies, I finally found [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and straightened things up so that it builds without issues However, I have to intellisense for any of the views (.cshtml files): @using, @model, @html.*, @styles... nothing works. I must have broken the reference to the razor view engine not being able to parse them properly. I have double checked the web.configs and cannot see anything. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: No can do woithout VS2013 it seems:

Look at this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968304/create-and-run-mvc-5-project-in-vs-2012/19124665#19124665

Comment: Please vote for the corresponding bug at Microsoft connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806348/razor-intellisense-does-not-work-in-visual-studio-2012-after-upgrading-to-mvc-5-razor-3

Comment: "MVC 5/Razor 3 tooling support for VS 2012 has not shipped yet. We hope to ship this support in Mid November (2013)."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 has now been released and should resolved the MVC5 intellisense issue with VS 2012.

> This release brings a ton of great improvements, and include some
>   fantastic enhancements to ASP.NET MVC 5, Web API 2, Scaffolding and
>   Entity Framework to users of Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2012
>   Express for Web.

You can download the update: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Answer (score 30):

Went through the same agony, and was working without intellisense in views for about 3 weeks.
Then I finally found it. It started working when I switched webpages setting to version 3 in web.config.

So in my web.config this was version 2.0.0.0, after i updated to 3.0.0.0 it started to work

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
     ...
</appSettings>
```

Hopfully this was your issue to and will help becouse I feel your pain :)

**--------------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE:**   For others who are still looking for a fix for this issues in a post-MVC5 update, this helped me: In the `~/Views/web.config`, updating from MVC 5.2.2.0 to 5.2.3.0 using Nuget did not update this line:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Updating `5.2.2.0` to `5.2.3.0` brought Intellisense back to life.  You may have to close the view and re-open it to get the Intellisense to load.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue with a clean 2013 installation.

Comment: Excellent...Thanks!  This worked for me (note that I installed the Web Tools 2013 first so it might be the combination of the two).

Comment: Worked for me too - VS2013. I didn't need to restart VS. I just closed my view and re-opened - suddenly it works!

Comment: Changing 2.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0 did it for me, although rather than reloading Visual Studio, you can unload and then reload the specific project.

Answer (score 7):

I had try all that and  other stuffs in my case the solution was changes this line that is in Views-WebConfig inside

```
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

to

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: can't believe i missed only that one version number. made all the difference

Answer (score 1):

While the above answers may resolve most of these problems, my problem was apparently caused by a VS Extension I had installed. Please see Answer provided by Emran Hussain here: [Visual Studio 2013 IntelliSense stops working for ASP.NET MVC5 Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471887/visual-studio-2013-intellisense-stops-working-for-asp-net-mvc5-controllers)

His answer was spot on for me, even though my problem was with intellisense on my Razor Views only. I disabled the extension, and restarted VS2013 and intellisense is working again with no problems. Like Emran, I'm hesitant to blame the maker of the extension (AzureXplorer by ClumsyLeaf software), because I think this may be a VS issue?

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous solutions worked for me. I'm using VS 2012 and MVC 5. This is what I did to make it work:

1. I installed Web Tools 2013 as explained in the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx
2. I checked /web.config and /Views/web.config and fixed some version issues. In my case I have MVC 5.2 so it was important to do a correct MVC biding like this:

Also, it's important to mark this:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip of the "@model" tag at the very top of my razor view file stated that autofac 3.4.0.0 could not be found. All my projects used Autofac 3.1.5, so I added a redirect in web.config to quickly work around the issue:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.0.0" newVersion="3.1.5" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        ...
```

My intellisense was back and I then deferred the final fix to a low prio task :D