# After MVC 5.2.2 Upgrade EditorFor not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

After upgrading to MVC 5.2 from 4.0, all the editorfor and @Url functions aren't recognised by visual studio (no intellisense and reports them as errors), however it runs OK. How can I make Visual studio recognise them?

Comment: The [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500371/update-from-mvc4-to-mvc5-no-intellisense-in-views) might help

Comment: Typically, this is an issue in your Views folder web.config and having the incorrect Razor/MVC/WebPages assemblies referenced (should be 3.0.0.0 instead of 2.0.0.0)

Comment: I had looked at the various web.config files, and corrected them to no avail. I've since reverted as it was too frustrating..