# Direct download link to ASP.NET MVC 5 for VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking for a direct link to ASP.NET MVC 5 install package for Visual Studio 2012, in downloads of asp.net i found only packages with Azure, but i need package without it.

Comment: Have you tried nuget package manager?

Comment: I need not only runtime packages for concrete app, but template which allow me create a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project from New item menu.

Comment: I just found this [link](http://egypt.silverkeytech.com/blogs/third-world/2013/8/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-5-RC1-in-your-visual-studio-2012). might be helpful to you. Let me know how it works if you try.

Comment: Thanke you @th1rdey3, but i found another [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) where described how to upgrade ASP.NET MVC 4 project to ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: I think your link talks about upgrading an existing mvc 4 project to mvc 5 and working with it in vs 2013. whereas mine talks about creating a mvc 4 project and upgrading it to mvc 5 (rc 1) in vs 2012.

Comment: Yes, but this solution acceptable and for VS 2012. As i understood, the ASP.NET MVC 5 install package is not ready yet, and will be accessible in nov 2013.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19124665/132528), and [one of the responses to this Razor Intellisense bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806348/razor-intellisense-does-not-work-in-visual-studio-2012-after-upgrading-to-mvc-5-razor-3), Microsoft does not plan on shipping tooling for VS2012 and MVC5 until November 2013.

**UPDATE**

Per IT Hit WebDav's comments, I wanted to update that [Microsoft has released ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for VS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the links. I found these info too.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Microsoft released ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 that installs MVC 5 for VS 2012

Comment: Thank you, @ITHitWebDAV. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: `ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for VS2012.` is now available in `ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2` see @ http://i.stack.imgur.com/pRTSe.jpg

Answer (score 8):

For Download Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012

Go to link: [Announcing Release of Asp.Net and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Then click download link for Download Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012

This PACKAGE include MVC 5, EF 6, NuGet 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Although If you want to install ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET Web API 2 into VS 2012 Ultimage so, you can download MSI installer from 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532.

I have downloaded and installed just know. I got MVC 5 and Web API 2
:)

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web" for free. It includes MVC 5. Download Link : 
[Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40747)