# VS2012 add areas to an existing project? start over? with MVC5 or stick with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm an beginner learning MVC4/VS2012. With many hours help from SO and Contoso University , I've gotten my demonstration website up with an SQL db and have a trial user. About 6 months experience now. As happens the project has expanded. So some advise please.

My current project has 10 models and 12 controllers, I've just activated SimpleMembership and need to replicate all of the ASP membership stuff and then have a long way to go with role based menus etc. I will probably add 50 models and controllers to CRUD the additional models. I've seen "areas" and think my solution will be much cleaner using that concept. I also see MVC5 and EF6.

When I started learning last fall, I was reluctant to upgrade to MVC5 EF6 because scaffolding was no longer supported and did not feel confident enough to workaround. Also some issue with Razor was mentioned. I now see a NUGet package for MVC scaffolding.

I was perusing this site today and found a post about AREAS that suggested to a person that had a single entity in a demo project, that it would be cleanest if he started over with MVC5.

So please, you 'old timers' with a much greater perspective on the work ahead, should I try to add areas (and upgrade to MVC5/EF6 with my current project), or keep on slogging with MVC4.

I have not seen any "how to" post relating to adding the AREAs concept to an functioning project ( that is, create the AREA concept, then move existing controllers, models, etc. into a new area folder, [the work will be in registering the routes?]).

Any forewarning of pitfalls would be appreciated.

A big question is can I run MVC5/EF6 in VS2012 ultimate or is this a forced upgrade?

Not the normal programming question, but I hope educational enough to meet SO standards.

JW

Comment: Can you do what you want with mvc 4?  If so, no reason to upgrade, and you can always upgrade later if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

An area is basically a mini mvc structure. It is used to separate things in your application. Other than having to specify the area in your routes and registering your areas in global.asax they work identically to the main mvc site structure. The question regarding areas is do you need to organize your site more than it already is? Perhaps you have certain areas of your application that you want to cordon off (maybe apply security a certain way). Or maybe you are writing an app and each area represents a module that can be included or not.

As far as running things in VS2012 ultimate, since VS2012 visual studio supports round tripping so you should be fine:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-compatibility-aka-project-round-tripping.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to denote your model entities and scenarios of your application and then based on them (if you have different modules, domains and ...) and then create you presentation later. MVC areas are so-called a sub mvc to provide you to have grouped and related scenarios separately, although you can use them for other proposes for example admin or users part of you application. 
if you really want to use the MVC5 or Entity framework new features, then try to upgrade your application to them(because it could me more cost effective in some cases).
you can also simply upgrade your project to MVC5 and EF6 with needing to migrate to VS2013 :
[Create and Run MVC 5 Project in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968304/create-and-run-mvc-5-project-in-vs-2012)